# Google Play get Subscription price with VAT

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Checking out the API for the Google Play IAB v3, the response for the `getSkuDetails()` returns `price`, `price_amount_micros` and `price_currency_code`. Unfortunately, `The price does not include tax.` Does anybody know of any other way of getting the full price for a purchase or a IAB/subscription item?

Reference: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#billing-interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so apparently the API docs suck. Wow, what a surprise. The `price` value has VAT included. Now the follow up question would be, is there any way of getting the VAT free price?

Comment: also, you need to publish your app, or else `getSkuDetails()` will return `null`.

Comment: According to google it does NOT return the price including tax and it does not return prices including taxes for me currently when I'm testing my billingclient setup.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails#getPrice()

Answer (score 3):

I'm also confused by this. I think it might be determined by whether or not you set your price in the Play Console to include tax or not:

[image]

So, my guess is that in your case, perhaps you have set your pricing template to use "price includes applicable tax"? I haven't verified this. Also, the fact that there is no way to get your price free of VAT is probably because Google doesn't want to be repsonsible for calculating country specific tax rules. It's too much of a pain in the arse, and can change at any time.

This is all just guess work, would be good if someone could verify this. It's difficult to easily test this kind of stuff.